# SAS optimal binning

Tags: sas, cart, binning

In SAS enterprise miner we have the optimal binning feature which allows you to transform continuous variables into an ordered set of bins. The binning, as  I read from one of their docs, is done so that the log odds of the predicted categorical variable (good/bad) is monotonically increasing or decreasing.

Can we use classification trees to kind of achieve the same result?. Like build a tree with only one variable and how many which splits we can get with sufficiently different log odds.

Comment: His this estimator been verified to be optimal in a traditional statistical sense?  Binning is usually a suboptimal approach.